# ViewPager2 MarginPageTransformer doesn't work

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

Margin is well applied when swipe.
However, if data is deleted and new data is allocated by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, then the margin is applied strangely.

```
viewpager.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0)
viewpager.setPageTransfromer(MarginPageTransformer(margin))
```

This is my code. What's the problem?...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"`.

```xml
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```